# Работа с изображением ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Программа заключается в работе с базой данных работников. Не получается загрузить изображения из представления в бд и из бд в представление для показа

Модель работников:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace EmployeeBase.Models
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Byte[] Foto { get; set; }
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

        public int? DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public Department Department { get; set; }

        // If i use this - my code dosen't work
        //public HttpPostedFileBase FotoFromView { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Контроллер:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.IO;

using EmployeeBase.Models;

namespace EmployeeBase.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        CompanyContext db = new CompanyContext();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var employees = db.Employees.Include(e => e.Department);
            return View(employees.ToList());
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult CreateEmployee()
        {
            SelectList EmpList = new SelectList(db.Departments, "Id", "Name");
            ViewBag.EmpList = EmpList;
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CreateEmployee(Employee employee, HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            MemoryStream target = new MemoryStream();

            file.InputStream.CopyTo(target);
            byte[] data = target.ToArray();

            employee.Foto = data;
            db.Employees.Add(employee);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

Представление `Index`:

```html
@model IEnumerable<EmployeeBase.Models.Employee> 

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Company";
}

<h2>ООО "Моя Компания"</h2>
<p>
    <a href="/Home/CreateEmployee">
        <input type="button" value="New" />
    </a>
</p>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Birth</th>
        <th>Foto</th>
        <th>Department</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BirthDate)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Foto)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Department.Name)</td>
            <td>
                <a href="/Home/EditEmployee/@item.Id">
                    <input type="button" value="Edit" />
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="/Home/DeleteEmployee/@item.Id">
                    <input type="button" value="Delete" />
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Представление `CreateEmployee`:

```html
@model EmployeeBase.Models.Employee

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<h2>Добавление нового сотрудника</h2>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Сотрудник</legend>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => modelItem.Name)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Birth</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => modelItem.BirthDate)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Foto</td>
            <td><input type="file" name="file"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Department</td>
            <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => modelItem.DepartmentId, ViewBag.EmpList as SelectList)</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Add" />   
}
</fieldset>
```

Comment: http://metanit.com/sharp/articles/mvc/9.php неплохая статья по этому поводу.

Comment: https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/21.3.php ещё одна статья, я как раз по ней реализовывал загрузку файлов

Answer (score 2):

Ну загрузить изображение можно примерно так:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (file != null)
        {
            var image = new MyImage() 
            {
                MimeType = file.ContentType,
                Data = new byte[file.ContentLength]
            }  

            file.InputStream.Read(image.Data, 0, file.ContentLength); 
        }

        repository.SaveImage(image);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    else
    {
        return View(product);
    }
}
```

Отображение:

```
 public FileContentResult GetImage(int imageId)
 {
     var image = repository.Images.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == imageId);

     if (image != null)
     {
         return File(image.Data, image.MimeType); 
     }
     else
       return null;
}
```

View:

```
@model YourApp.Entities.MyImage

<div class="item">

        <img src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "YourController", 
             new { Model.ID })" />
</div>
```

Тип представляющий изображение:

```
public class MyImage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public byte[] Data { get; set; }
    public string MimeType { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: зачем проверка на null, если у тебя FirstOrDefault

Comment: И что не так? `FirstOrDefault` может вернуть `null`, если ничего найдено не будет.