# Вывод картинок во View ASP.NET

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Вот моя модель:

```
public class RelNewsViewModelItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<NewsImageViewModelItem> NewsImages { get; set; }

}

public class NewsImageViewModelItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public byte[] ImageItem { get; set; }
    public int NewsId { get; set; }

}

public class RelNewsViewModel
{
    public List<RelNewsViewModelItem> RelNews { get; set; }
}
```

В коллекции `NewsImages`  находится несколько картинок.

Как правильно вывести во View?

```
@model Schedule.BLL.Model.RelNewsViewModel

    @foreach (var item in Model.RelNews)
       {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.Id</td>
                <!--<td>item.NewsImages</td>-->
                <td>@item.Title</td>
                <td>@item.Body</td>
            </tr>
        }
```

Comment: Можно использовать data: URI

Comment: @Alex78191 я уже разобрался, сейчас опубликую ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так мне удалось вывести коллекцию картинок:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.RelNews)
{
<tr>
    <td>@item.Id</td>
    <td>
        @foreach (var img in item.NewsImages)
        {
            <img src="data:image;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(img.ImageItem)" class="img-tests"/>
        }
    </td>
    <td>@item.Title</td>
    <td>@item.Body</td>
```

Comment: [Ещё способ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/552805/184217).